# Is there a way to run JavaScript from a string in browser with imported libraries?

Tags: javascript, function, import, scope, svelte

I have a function that lets me run a JavaScript function in the browser:

```js
export async function executeFunction(data: LoadOutput, input: Record<string, any>): Promise<any> {
    let args = [];
    for (let param of data.functionTree[0].parameters) {
        let value = input[param.name];

        if(!value) {
            return undefined;
        }

        args.push(value);
    }

    let func = new Function('return ' + data.jsCode)();
    return await func.call(null, ...args);
}
```

It all works, but now I want to add more functionality by being able to use external libraries.
I tried adding imports in the string but this didn't work and resulted in errors

`There was an error: Module name, 'image-conversion' does not resolve to a valid URL.`

Is there a way I can import external libraries?
Preferably by not having to pass them as a parameter (That's what ChatGPT suggested but would require a massive refactor of my code)

Is there maybe a library that does the same thing as Function but lets me add external libraries to the scope?

For additional information: I'm using SvelteKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now managed to do it.
I imported a library (I used lodash as an example for testing) and saved it into a const

```
import lodash from 'lodash';
const libraries = { lodash }
```

I pass it into the Function call like this

```
let func = new Function(...Object.keys(libraries), 'return ' + data.jsCode)(...Object.values(libraries));
return await func.call(null, ...args);
```

And now I can use lodash when calling a function from a string.

Here is my testing example:

```
"libraryTest": "function libraryTest(text: string): { result: string } {\n" +
    "    const result = lodash.toUpper(text);\n" +
    "    return { result };\n" +
    "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Such dependencies cannot be fully dynamic unless you somehow ship all your node modules and do some complicated on-the-fly bundling, but you can probably e.g. somewhere import the module via an [URL import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports) and use that.

```js
import imageConversionUrl from 'image-conversion?url';
```

```js
`import ... from ${JSON.stringify(imageConversionUrl)}`
```

URL imports bundle the dependency and output it as an asset in the build.
(More commonly used for media assets so they can be used e.g. as an image `src`. For a list of file types URL imports are the implicit default.)